# Clear in-flight elements in a stream when an upstream publisher is restarted in Spring Project Reactor?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a publisher that executes a long-running and large query on MongoDB and returns the data in a [Flux](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html). Entities that are marked in the database as "processed" will be filtered out and the entities are then buffered and passed to a [concatMap](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concatMap-java.util.function.Function-) operator (so that all buffered ≤elements are processed before elements in the next buffer are processed). It looks something like this:

```java
Flux<Entity> entitiesFromMongoDb = myMongoRepository.executeLargeQuery();
entitiesFromMongoDb.filter(entity -> !entity.isProcessed())
                   .buffer(10)
                   .concatMap(bufferedEntityList ->  
                                    Flux.fromIterable(bufferedEntityList)
                                        .flatMap(makeExternalCall)
                                        .then()));
```

Where `makeExternalCall` calls a third-party remote server *and* sets the entity to `processed` after the call has been made. In most cases this works fine, but when the remote server is really slow or has an error then `makeExternalCall` will retry (with exponential backoff) the operation to the remote server. In some cases it can take quite a while before all 10 external calls have been processed. In fact it can take so long that the `myMongoRepository.executeLargeQuery()` publisher is restarted and the query is executed again. Now we run into a problem that I'll try to describe here:

1. Entity A is read from the database (i.e. it's returned in the flux produced by `myMongoRepository.executeLargeQuery()`). It's not yet marked as "processed" which means that `entity.isProcessed()` will return `false` and it'll be retained in the stream.
2. The external server is really slow or down so that `makeExternalCall` is forced to retry the operation *before* entity A has been marked as "processed" in the DB.
3. `myMongoRepository.executeLargeQuery()` is restarted and the query is executed again.
4. Entity A is read from the database once more. But the problem is that there's already another instance of entity A in-flight since it has not yet been marked as "processed" by the previous call to `myMongoRepository.executeLargeQuery()`.
5. This means that `makeExternalCall` will be called twice for entity A, which is not optimal!

I could make an additional request to the DB and check the status of `processed` for each entity in the `makeExternalCall` method, but this will cause additional load (since an extra request is necessary for each entity) to the DB which is not optimal.

So my question is:

Is there a way to somehow "restart" the entire stream, and thus clear intermediary buffers (i.e. remove entity A that is in-flight from the ongoing stream) when the MongoDB query triggered by `myMongoRepository.executeLargeQuery()` is restarted/re-executed? Or is there a better way to handle this?

I'm using Spring Boot `2.2.4.RELEASE`, project reactor `3.3.2.RELEASE` and `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive` `2.2.4.RELEASE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure If I understood the problem completely. But trying to answer as it sounds interesting.

As you need to be aware of the requests which are already being processed by the `makeExternalCall`, can you maintain a set / local cache which contains the entities which are being processed?

```
Set<Entity> inProgress = new HashSet<>(); 

Flux<Entity> entitiesFromMongoDb = myMongoRepository.executeLargeQuery();

entitiesFromMongoDb.filter(entity -> !entity.isProcessed())
                   .buffer(10)
                   .map(bufferedEntityList -> {  // remove the inprogress requests to avoid redundant processing
                        bufferedEntityList.removeIf(inProgress::contains);
                        return bufferedEntityList;
                   })
                   .concatMap(bufferedEntityList ->  
                                    inProgress.addAll(bufferedEntityList);
                                    Flux.fromIterable(bufferedEntityList)
                                        .flatMap(makeExternalCall) //assuming once processed, it emits the entity object
                                        .map(entity -> {   //clear growing set
                                            inProgress.remove(entity);
                                            return entity;
                                        })
                                        .then()));
```

This approach is not a good solution when you need to scale your application horizontally. In that case instead of maintaining a local cache, you could go for an external cache server like `redis`.

Comment: I don't think there's a better solution than this so I'm going to accept it, altough it wasn't exactly what I asked for. Thanks!